# Is there any tool or facility or command line command built into windows 8.1 that replaces migwiz?

Tags: windows-8.1, migration

Sadly the `migwiz` tool (Windows Easy Transfer) in windows 8.1 is a legacy/lobotomized useless thing, that can accept a backup made with Windows 7 or 8.0, but cannot generate a backup from the original PC if you are moving a person's profile from computer A to computer B, and both are on Windows 8.1.

Is there some built in tool to help with moving the same information that migwiz formerly migrated  from computer A to computer B that is built into windows 8.1, that works if both machines are on Windows 8.1?

The last known working configuration is if windows 8.0 is the originator, and windows 8.1 is the receiving PC. No information on replacement tools appears to be available on Microsoft's site.

Comment: If you don't need the profile to work anymore, take ownership of the profile folder as an administrator and transfer it by hand.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid.  It seems to me Microsoft should have provided some kind of PROFILE-move-tool even if it's not polished.

Comment: PowerShell would be the tool and being an admin is required to do it ( you transfer all personal files ) everything else is handled by domain scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy C:\Windows\system32\migwiz\ from windows 8, and use it on your 8.1 box to recover the removed functionality.